# Unable to send attachment to Discord channel

Tags: file, discord.py

I am unable to send a file (created by a bot and stored in a directory on the server by said bot) to the user as an attachment. Here is my code:

```
import discord, os
from discord.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')

file = 'processed_logs.txt'
some_directory = 'some_directory'

@bot.command()
async def send_file(ctx):
    with open(f"{os.getcwd}/Cache/{some_directory}/{file}", 'rb') as attachment: 
            await ctx.send(f"{file}", file=discord.File(attachment))

bot.run(bot_token)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are you seeing an error message?

Comment: Are you sure your path is correct? This should be working, the only thing I can think of is that maybe your path is incorrect.

Comment: It does not spit out an error message and the path is correct as the bot saved the file in that path and I’m simply using the same variable that it saved the file in. Still can’t figure out where I’m  going wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found out where I was going wrong, the file description comes AFTER, not BEFORE the file-path or file-object! So the answer is:

```
import discord, os
from discord import File
from discord.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')

file = 'processed_logs.txt'
some_directory = 'some_directory'

@bot.command()
async def send_file(ctx):
    with open(f"{os.getcwd}/Cache/{some_directory}/{file}", 'rb') as attachment: 
            await ctx.send(file=File(attachment, f"{file}"))

bot.run(bot_token)
```

Another solution (as stated by @KickBull):

```
import discord, os
from discord import File
from discord.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')

file = 'processed_logs.txt'
some_directory = 'some_directory'

@bot.command()
async def send_file(ctx):
    await ctx.send(file=File(f"{os.getcwd}/Cache/{some_directory}/{file}", f"{file}"))

bot.run(bot_token)
```

Answer (score 0):

discord.File() takes in the path of the file. You don't need to use the open() function.